# mocha and supertest.agent not working as expected

Tags: express, mocha.js, supertest, node-async, superagent

I'm trying to write some tests where I need to authenticate first. If I make multiple requests in "before()" I get connection refused. If I split it between "before()" and "it()" it works but I cannot acheive what I want.

Code I want to work:

```
var agent = request.agent(myExpressApp),
      token;
    before(function(done) {
      async.series([
        function(cb) {
          agent
            .post('/1/auth/login')
            .send({
              email: 'john@smith.com',
              password: 'j0hn_Sm1TH'
            })
            .expect(200)
            .end(cb);
        }, function(cb) {
          agent
            .get('/1/auth/authorize')
            .query({
              response_type: 'token',
              client_id: 'some id',
              redirect_uri: 'http://ignore'
            })
            .expect(302)
            .end(function(err, res) {
              /* console.log(arguments) = { '0': 
                { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
                  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
                  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
                  syscall: 'connect' } }*/
              if (err) return cb(err);
              cb();
            });
        }
      ], done);
    });
    it('some authenticated task', function(done) {
      // do something else
      done();
    });
```

Code that is working:

```
var agent = request.agent(myExpressApp),
      token;
    before(function(done) {
      async.series([
        function(cb) {
          agent
            .post('/1/auth/login')
            .send({
              email: 'john@smith.com',
              password: 'j0hn_Sm1TH'
            })
            .expect(200)
            .end(cb);
        }, function(cb) {
          cb();
        }
      ], done);
    });
    it('some authenticated task', function(done) {
      agent
        .get('/1/auth/authorize')
        .query({
          response_type: 'token',
          client_id: 'some id',
          redirect_uri: 'http://ignore'
        })
        .expect(302)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Bizarrely if I add `function(cb) { process.nextTick(cb); }` to the async.series it works as desired. This seems a bit hacky. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered [issue 153 with superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/153). Annoyingly and magically, superagent looks at the arity of the callback function you pass to it. If the function is declared accepting 2 arguments, superagent conforms to the node convention of `(error, result)`, however, if the callback function looks like it expects any other number of arguments (zero in the case of use with async.js), it invokes the function as just `callback(res)` which I guess TJ thought would be nice for the browser, but for node it totally breaks convention.

The exact line of code in question is [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/bcd812cb1e7f4dbaffc862f9be79b27496f7b0b1/lib/client.js#L782)

Comment: I understood this to change `cb` to `function (err, res) { cb(err) }` but it still doesn't work as desired. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Please post a complete updated example. It's too hard to follow an isolated snippet. The problem is `.end(cb)` when `.end` is a superagent request and `cb` is an async.js callback. That needs an extra wrapper: `.end(function(err, res) {cb(err, res)})`.

Comment: It looks like your issue is more related to https://github.com/tj/supertest/issues/126 which https://github.com/tj/supertest/pull/137 may have broken for agent.